# Git from the command line doesn't work, but using a git client (like SmartGit) does

Tags: git, command-line

I am on a Mac and I normally run most of my git commands through the command line. All of a sudden this morning, all my command line git commands stopped working. If I type 'git status', the terminal appears to hang for about a minute, and ends up not displaying anything:

```
01412b-malberts:f2 sbanerjee$ git status
01412b-malberts:f2 sbanerjee$
```

Other git commands like, pull, push, and branch all have similar behavior.

Strangely, using a git GUI like SmartGit (which actually uses the same git executable as the command line) seems to work fine. I can see modified files, push, pull, everything.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing git, re-cloning my repo, and restarting my laptop. Can anyone help me get my git commands working from the command line?

Comment: Try doing `which git` to make sure you are actually running git, and not something else.

Comment: Also check if your shell is the problem. You could also check the exit status of the git commands, look inside your `.git/` directory if anything is off (less likely since the GUI works).

Comment: I ran which git, and it is pointing to the correct location:/usr/local/git/bin/git . Any other thoughts?

Comment: I assume /usr/local/git/bin is on your path right? since it worked before? Also, have you tried executing it with the full path?

Comment: Yes, it is on my path, executing with full path has same results.

Comment: some troubleshooting sanity-tests: what happens if you type `git foobar`? how about `git help status`? `git --version`? `echo $PATH`? Are there other git commands which _do_ provide output? What happens when you type `git status` in a folder which is not a git repo? What about when you type that command as a root with sudo?  -- P.S. appending these results as an edit to your question (instead of adding another comment) may be easier to read.

Comment: Anything interesting turn up in `/var/log/system.log` when these commands fail?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue: my GUI works fine but the command line just hangs on *all* git commands. Hit return again and it goes back to the prompt. Nothing interesting to report in the `system.log`. I have a horrible suspicion it has to do with my noodling with the OS X Keychain.

Comment: I had the same issue. Smart Git working but not the command line
I noticed I have XCode installed and updated.
You may need to update your "Command line tools" or install it if you have XCode
This should fix it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please disregard this question entirely... Sorry guys, but I was trolled by a coworker who ran a script in my terminal that made my mac use SimpleText to speak out all output from git commands...

Answer (score 0):

Try running git with some debugging on:

```
GIT_TRACE=2 git status
```

Sounds like a local (library?) issue rather than a git bug.